# Hint need in contour integration of ∫ ( 0 to 2π) cos^2 3θ/ ( 1- 2acosθ + a^2)

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I would appreciate a hint on this question not a solution. To be precise, I am having difficulty due to cos^2 3θ.

Comment: Not sure why you're referring to this as a contour integral.

Comment: Because my book stated it